# Why is second generic type information lost when using "infer"?

Tags: typescript, generics

So I have a abstract base class which receives a value of `ValueType` and has a function which is able to transform it to `TransformedType`. This is solved via two generics:

```js
abstract class Base<ValueType, TransformedType> {
  public abstract transformValue: (value: ValueType) => TransformedType;
}
```

Now I have two classes which properly extend from `Base`, one for `ValueType` string the other one for numbers:

```js
interface StringTransformed {
  someValue: string;
}

class DerivedString extends Base<string, StringTransformed> {
  public transformValue = (value: string): StringTransformed => {
    return { someValue: value + "someValue" };
  };
}
```

```js
interface NumberTransformed {
  valuePlusPlus: number;
}

class DerivedNumber extends Base<number, NumberTransformed> {
  public transformValue = (value: number): NumberTransformed => {
    return { valuePlusPlus: value + 1 };
  };
}
```

After that I create a type `Fields` which requires a generic type `T` from type `object`:

```js
type Fields<T extends object> = {
  [A in keyof T]: any extends Base<T[A], infer P> ? Base<T[A], P>: never
};
```

**Usage example:**

```js
type MainType = { x: string; y: number };

const fields: Fields<MainType> = {
  x:  new DerivedString("test"),
  y: new DerivedNumber(2)
};

const transformed = fields.x.transformValue("anystring");
```

The problem here is that type information about `TransformedType` is lost because it is `unknown`:

[image]
[image]

In contrast to that type information about `ValueType` stays correct.

**Questions:**

1. How to properly take a generic type as it is without adding any restrictions to it?
   Is it correct to use `infer` here?
   Why the type information is getting lost?
2. Am I able to remove the `TransformedType` from the generic argument of `Base` and just use it in the `transformValue` function?(`ValueType` need for other functions etc. inside `Base` but `TransformedType` only for the `transformValue` function)

**EDIT:**

As desired by the comments I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-mcnulty-rfnet) with an minimal example of the use case. Basically there are some `any` casts I can not get around, which is my actual problem.

In general I want to write a library in react for handling form state, so it really needs to be a very generic approach. Please keep in mind that this example is really really simplified and is much more complex in reality.

Comment: It doesn't look like type information is "lost" as much as it was never there in the first place.  `any extends ...infer T...` is hardly ever going to do much for you, since you're analyzing `any`.  Why not just take the annotation off of `fields` and have `const fields = {x: new DerivedString(), y: new DerivedNumber()}`?  If that doesn't work could you give a [mcve] that shows where?   Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz i edit my question and added a codesandbox. Hopefully it will help to understand my issue a bit better. Sadly i can't just use the annotation of `fields`, because I expect a generic `Fields<T>` as argument of a function (see codesandbox in `transformFields.ts`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, for Question 2 first: yes, you can mostly remove the second type parameter and have it default to `unknown` if you define it like this:

```
// default second parameter
abstract class Base<T, U = unknown> {
  public abstract transformValue: (value: T) => U;
}


interface StringTransformed {
  someValue: string;
}

class DerivedString extends Base<string> {
  public transformValue = (value: string): StringTransformed => {
    return { someValue: value + "someValue" };
  };
}

interface NumberTransformed {
  valuePlusPlus: number;
}

class DerivedNumber extends Base<number> {
  public transformValue = (value: number): NumberTransformed => {
    return { valuePlusPlus: value + 1 };
  };
}
```

The actual classes `DerivedString` and `DerivedNumber` still know the types returned by their `transformValue()` method.

---

Back to Question 1... first, your definition of `Fields` might as well be this:

```
type Fields<T = any> = { [K in keyof T]: Base<T[K]> };
```

It's pretty much the same.  Note that I gave a default type parameter of `any` so that `Fields` by itself means `Fields<any>`.

Now, as I commented, you don't really need to annotate any particular constant as being of some specific `Fields<...>` type; the type inference will take care of it for you and you will be warned if you try to pass a bad thing into your eventual `transformFields()` function.  Still, if you want to be warned early about a bad constant, you can make a helper function like this:

```
const asFields = <F extends Fields>(fields: F) => fields;
```

This will complain if you give it a value that doesn't match.  So this will be fine:

```
const fields = asFields({
  x: new DerivedString(),
  y: new DerivedNumber()
});
```

while this will give an error:

```
const badFields = asFields({
  x: "whoops", // error! string is not a valid Base 
  y: new DerivedNumber() 
})
```

And the compiler will remember what `fields` actually does:

```
fields.x.transformValue("anystring").someValue; // okay
```

If you have a specific type `T` you need your `fields` constant to transform, you can make a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) helper function to specify `T` manually and have it infer the rest:

```
const asValueFields = <T>() => <F extends Fields<T>>(fields: F) => fields;
```

Then this works:

```
const fieldsAlso = asValueFields<MainType>()({
  x: new DerivedString(),
  y: new DerivedNumber()
});
```

but this fails:

```
const badFieldsAlso = asValueFields<MainType>()({
  x: new DerivedNumber(), // error! string is not number
  y: new DerivedString()  // error! number is not string
});
```

And it still remembers the specific output type:

```
fieldsAlso.x.transformValue("anystring").someValue; // okay
```

---

Finally, let's implement `transformFields()`.  It's useful to describe the transformed output type given a `Fields` type.  Here's how I'd define it:

```
type TransformedType<F extends Fields> = {
  [K in keyof F]: F[K] extends Base<any, infer T> ? T : never
};
```

This might be the crux of the solution to "how do I prevent types from being lost"?  What you're doing above is taking a type `F` which knows exactly what input and output types it deals with, and pulling out the output type for each property.

So `transformFields` takes a `T` and an `F` and returns a `TransformedType<F>`:

```
const transformFields = <T extends object, F extends Fields<T>>(
  fields: F,
  values: T
): TransformedType<F> => {
  return (Object.keys(fields) as Array<keyof T>).reduce(
    <K extends keyof T>(transformedObj: TransformedType<F>, key: K) => ({
      ...transformedObj,
      [key]: (fields[key] as Base<T[K], TransformedType<F>[K]>).transformValue(
        values[key]
      )
    }),
    {} as TransformedType<F>
  );
};
```

The implementation is the same as the one from your code sandbox, with some carefully placed [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that what you're doing is okay.  Basically we assert that `Object.keys(fields)` will return an array of `T`'s keys, that `fields[key]` is a `Base` that takes in a `T[K]` and outputs a `TransformedType<F>[K]`, and that the `reduce()` accumulator is a `TransformedType<F>`.

Whew!  Let's use it:

```
const transformedMainType = transformFields(fields, { x: "", y: 1 });
transformedMainType.x.someValue; // okay
transformedMainType.y.valuePlusPlus; // okay
```

Looks good.  Note that you don't have to "prep" `fields` with the helper functions from before.  If you have a properly typed object literal, it will also just work:

```
const alsoWorks = transformFields(
  { x: new DerivedString(), y: new DerivedNumber() },
  { x: "", y: 1 }
);
alsoWorks.x.someValue; // okay
alsoWorks.y.valuePlusPlus; // okay
```

Okay that was a lot.  Hope that gives you some direction.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgHgBUAaBAVQQF4EBXAOwGtaB7Ad1oD4EBvAKAQQAO1EMgCWsBKEgx4CaMFpgAZkygBbAGrBk1HAC4EACgBu23QYIBKSp1IBuHgF8ePUbQg4oSuDgQBlaDcAcwIYRRV1HAATbj4EMCY1HC0dfXjA2iCHZx4UNAwAEU9RY2iAqGCEHAAPD1oojGwwfGlgzl5+IRFxOTDlVU0zXyoTIYNWzMsDcuDQhX7ImIp2uP4oHAhqKFpueMTksYRTVIQAagQAIgSklN0LhEcHfkenFzcPLx8EADlqNRBPHNwgNorF+MddAAFHRgaHUMAGWh-AFQbIuPLoBBFCqlKK-f6eKq1HD1Rq4PBIglQFadYRiCTyYHqW7DIwQtKUlFTH7IwF9CJJJY0-gIdabba7dlw2Ewgzss4IACMDyeKtePAgAE8BL4ALLANwEbWsrgIarjDJZBCaxG8qBqjXGhAAMVEOGQDUIlEktE1nCopoA2gBpBBuBD0HCaphKBAEAC6Bia+AIIfjnBeuSYikQaFd7oa3rwzqJdUL+Y9YHYhiUbsrBmd1mWCFrBbADizOZbdcLVDzPbAhg6ZsROBYWOKuJmmUMliIcRtCFoY4nOOi+JRs6clg7sGzkAQIGAUQrvckYFPg+H5suLAAFkwmAIwBcSAB6N9VKBQVQAQnSFSZGGGDMLmRzaKIMTJguo7jtiJTrnaW6ODuLitpWAB01QYYyCyDKkhgXAomoTEEFyWBh1wHKkdgIB+CBMPQwCaui+65mALKXkWBDVk2nDFqWJLlgOhDsNW6ENA2fHdm2u5sTJlYAILIAk3poJxIn6oaxq8UOcQ3sucGTmUlqzvO-CLoZq4IXiSGWNucldkeJ4Dspql9hxQyXngWm0EaOq6desHWbiG6eGZdGfp4P5QP+pHAUuTCIJyngwUuK7wVOpnWPR0V-kudoJaBAHBA5aGuSpTBYTh-IDCyhHEaR5GUfsLK0fRjHMS4Wo6nGtWLP5+AljUZYYJe-pgggIZhjskbRrGzqJi6aaCaSWDksRJBuEohI8QgAD8cYIKOpRQE4jkHrhApcVQXojUJGBMCAABWODwCQw3Emt3k8dWcQSQiLrmeBqSAwQPDckCeHRINxb+sKYpbDshgAPIvW9EAYXNg4A9YaAIIp37MXgc0xnG7AUesUTULAOCGKsCB4KG91raTsY8YYV0glEaPPRY-WCrDzrsCQc0GMG0l6SKIoYbLXOLLzwPS4Gc1LTWA4q1G8bnutzSEGmJBQwKMPGnDaYUzV8wCvVDPS+yYCa5q8a2wg9nSyhSvcI4OtG9zQvsHEqGZnuXby4KvmDd6YeXurbYkKaN4XHeUavtaBiKgATAAzA8qFh9EEfGtVVFtZFDFMSx+dRIXOoYZqGFSjC0rtZ+nUsZ2B7aAkADqqj0BgVDRwO9P8AnwWZSZgFBBFlkZcZtlUrODzA2Plyp4uyrOKhXdML3UD98XrVDC35ddTve8H-Xjfws3ZdtzwQA)

Comment: Wow, that's very helpful and detailed! Using it already in my code and works like a charm, thanks a lot typescript guru!